# manipulating sed context

Tags: sed

Here is my one-liner:

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/{$d;1d;p}' query
```

And query:

```
trash

BEGIN first
labas
END

nieko nėra

BEGIN second
iki
END
nesimato
```

I expect this result:

```
labas
iki
```

However, I get this:

```
BEGIN first
labas
END
BEGIN second
iki
END
```

What do I misunderstand about sed context? Shouldn't `{$d,1d;p}` delete first and last line of the matching input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it deletes any line of the matching input that is the first or last line of the file. You can see the effect if you remove the first two lines of `query` (so that the first line is "BEGIN").

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/{//!p}' file
labas
iki
```

Comment: Yes indeed it works, but does not help to explain why my version doesn't.. Thanks. Can you give me a pointer why? What exactly do these two slashes do for the context in those curly braces?

Comment: Your version will work but only when the range `/BEGIN/,/END/` is between the first and last lines of the file. The `//` is shorthand for the last matching regexp, in this case `/BEGIN/` and later on `/END/`. On these conditions it won't print out but on lines between it will.